# Self Driving Car (Game) using Convolutional Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, directx-11

I am using a convolutional neural network (tensorflow, alexnet) to drive a car in a game (Need For Speed). I'm just a student who wants to work with Machine Learning. I'm a total beginner at this.

Here's what my plan is:

1. Get training data
2. Balance  and shuffle it
3. Train a model
4. Test a model

The problem is that I am not finding a way to log or detect KeyPresses that I do while playing the game. I would like python to detect which keys I press, and store them in a npy array along with the game's frame image.

I did come across this piece of code which  logs KeyPresses, but only the alphabet keys. I want python to also detect arrow keys, space bar, etc.

```
import win32api as wapio
import time

keyList = ["\b"]
for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'£$/\\":
    keyList.append(char)

def key_check():
    keys = []
    for key in keyList:
        if wapi.GetAsyncKeyState(ord(key)):
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

I would also like a way to simulate KeyPresses, so that my model could actually drive a car.

I do have this piece of code, which works perfectly fine. I'm just asking for suggestions on this one.

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

W = 0x11
A = 0x1E
S = 0x1F
D = 0x20

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, 
    ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (True):
        PressKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
        ReleaseKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The next step is to actually collect the frame (image) of the game. I use cv2 to capture a region of my screen, where I play the game. I then:

1. convert it to grayscale
2. resize the image itself
3. save it as a numpy file (for every 1000 frames captured)

The data is captured perfectly fine, but once I have around 50 000 frames (or around 500 mb of data), it takes a long time to save the data. Sometimes, Python crashes while the numpy file is saving, resulting in a loss of all my training data.

Here's my code for capturing data:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from grabscreen import grab_screen
from getkeys import key_check
import os


def keys_to_output(keys):
    output = [0, 0, 0]

    if 'A' in keys:
        output[0] = 1
    elif 'D' in keys:
        output[2] = 1
    else:
        output[1] = 1

    return output


file_name = 'training_data.npy'

if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    print('File exists, loading previous data!')
    training_data = list(np.load(file_name))
else:
    print('File does not exist, starting fresh!')
    training_data = []


def main():
    for i in list(range(5))[::-1]:
        print(i + 1)
        time.sleep(1)

    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        print('Existing Training Data:' + str(len(training_data)))
        print('Capturing Data!')   
    else:
        print('Capturing Data Freshly!') 


    while True:
        screen = grab_screen(region=(40, 250, 860, 560))
        screen = cv2.resize(screen, (120, 56))
        screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        keys = key_check()
        output = keys_to_output(keys)
        training_data.append([screen, output])


        if len(training_data) % 1000 == 0:
            print('New Training Data: ' + str(len(training_data)))
            print('Saving Data!')
            np.save(file_name, training_data)
            print('Data saved succesfully! You can quit now.')
            print('Capturing data!')


main()
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to get my training data. Also, I heard about using PyTables, but I'm not sure of how to use it for my program.

After this, I shuffle my data, and balance it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

train_data = np.load('training_data.npy')

print('Training Data: ' + str(len(train_data)))
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
print(df.head())
print(Counter(df[1].apply(str)))

lefts = []
rights = []
forwards = []

shuffle(train_data)

for data in train_data:
    img = data[0]
    choice = data[1]

    if choice == [1, 0, 0]:
        lefts.append([img, choice])
    elif choice == [0, 1, 0]:
        forwards.append([img, choice])
    elif choice == [0, 0, 1]:
        rights.append([img, choice])
    else:
        print('no matches!!!')


forwards = forwards[:len(lefts)][:len(rights)]
lefts = lefts[:len(forwards)]
rights = rights[:len(forwards)]

final_data = forwards + lefts + rights

shuffle(final_data)
print('Final Balanced Data: ' + str(len(final_data)))
np.save('training_data_balanced.npy', final_data)
```

Model:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

def alexnet(width, height, lr):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

Training the model:

```
import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet

WIDTH = 120
HEIGHT = 56
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 15
MODEL_NAME = 'nfs-car-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

# for every epoch finished, save the model.
# therefore, if accuracy drops or loss increases, we can terminate the script.
# we will have a trained model with the best accuracy and previously saved epoch.

for i in range(EPOCHS):
    train_data = np.load('training_data_balanced.npy')

    train = train_data[:-10] # 80% of balanced data
    test = train_data[-10:] # 20% of balanced data

    X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1)
    Y = [i[1] for i in train]

    test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1)
    test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

    model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1,
              validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
              snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

    model.save(MODEL_NAME)
    print('Saved epoch: ' + str(i + 1))
```

Then of course, I test the model:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from grabscreen import grab_screen
from getkeys import key_check
from alexnet import alexnet
from directkeys import PressKey, ReleaseKey, W, A, D

WIDTH = 120
HEIGHT = 56
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 15
MODEL_NAME = 'nfs-car-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, EPOCHS)


def straight():
    PressKey(W)
    ReleaseKey(A)
    ReleaseKey(D)


def left():
    PressKey(W)
    PressKey(A)
    ReleaseKey(D) # added
    time.sleep(0.09)
    ReleaseKey(A)


def right():
    PressKey(W)
    PressKey(D)
    ReleaseKey(A) # added
    time.sleep(0.09)
    ReleaseKey(D)


model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)
model.load(MODEL_NAME)


def main():
    for i in list(range(5))[::-1]:
        print(i + 1)
        time.sleep(1)


    paused = False

    while True:

        if not paused:
            screen = grab_screen(region=(40, 250, 860, 560))
            screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            screen = cv2.resize(screen, (120, 56))

            prediction = model.predict([screen.reshape(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1)])[0]
            print(prediction)

            turn_thrush = .75
            fwd_thrush = 0.70

            if prediction[0] > turn_thrush:
                left()
            elif prediction[1] > fwd_thrush:
                straight()
            elif prediction[2] > turn_thrush:
                right()
            else:
                straight()

            keys = key_check()

            if 'T' in keys:
                if paused:
                    paused = False
                    print('Unpaused!')
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    print('Pausing!')
                    paused = True
                    ReleaseKey(A)
                    ReleaseKey(W)
                    ReleaseKey(D)
                    time.sleep(1)


main()
```

So yeah, this is what my idea is. Yet, I'm not able to fully apply this concept due to lack of proper information.

Answer (score 0):

1. the key press issue is bit too detail. just to let u know there is open source simulators from audacity course. and you maybe able to find some clue there.
2. for the large training set crash, you need to use the generator technique. it's more of streaming your training data (in smaller batches) to the training.
3. a simple model can achieve a lot too.

Please see this full implementation, including simulator, model training, test data, source code and summary from this project.

https://github.com/ericq/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3